# How can I set a default value in Doctrinemongodb document?

Tags: symfony-2.1, doctrine-mongodb

How can I set the default value in field.

In my document I need to set default value false for field emailnotify
In mogodb th default value should be zero.

Check my document

```
namespace xxx\xxxBundle\Document;

use FOS\UserBundle\Document\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Boolean
     */
    protected $emailnotify;

    /**
     * Sets the emailnotify.
     *
     * @param boolean $emailnotify
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmailnotify($emailnotify)
    {
        $this->emailnotify = (Boolean) $emailnotify;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isEmailnotify()
    {
        return $this->emailnotify;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found that setting the default value in the constructor works

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->emailnotify = false;
}
```

Of course just setting the class variable to false will work for most parts if you use Doctrine to fetch the Document again afterwards, but the property will not be persisted to MongoDB like with the above.